# ccrendertexture memory usage

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I have a lot of png images that I have optimized for memory usage.  I was wondering if this makes any difference for ccrendertexture.  I mean when I create a ccrendertexture and use sprites visit methods in it, does the original sprite file size have any significance or is it only the size of the ccrendertexture that matters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Original png size does matter only for your final app size. When the sprite is drawn it consume memory equal to width * height * bytesPerPixel, where bytesPerPixel most likely is 32. Example: 1024*1024 image with RGBA8 colors will occupy 4M in device memory.

CCRenderTexture will take additional space based on its size.